# Solving the linear system of equations

Tags: matrix-equations

Is it possible to solve non square matrix with Gaussian eliminations? OR any other way to solve a 6 equation with 8  variables?

Comment: Yes, you can apply Gaussian elimination to non-square matrices. As in the square case, you will get one solution, no solution, or several solutions.

Comment: @jflipp can you please explain me how to solve in Gaussian elimination, any referal links or any samples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. This is a general way to find all solutions (or show the non-existence of solutions) for a general system of linear equations.

Comment: can you explain  me how to solve? by giving any eaxmple. i searching in net a lot. but i dint get any sample.